# Include Phaser JS with React, PIXI not defined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, phaser-framework

I'm trying to include Phaser JS in a React component, but on load Webpack is returning a "Uncaught ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined" error. Here is my Webpack config file:

```
var path = require('path');
var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');
var phaserModule = path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/phaser/');
var phaser = path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/phaser-split.js'),
    pixi = path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/pixi.js'),
    p2 = path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/p2.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/polyfills.js', './src/main.js'],
    vendors: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-redux', 'redux', 'react-router', 'history', 'react-f1'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  /**
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    },
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
  },
   **/
  module: {
    /**
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
     **/
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash:7]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash:7]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /pixi\.js/,
        loader: 'expose?PIXI'
      },
      {
        test: /phaser-split\.js$/,
        loader: 'expose?Phaser'
      },
      {
        test: /p2\.js/,
        loader: 'expose?p2'
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'phaser': path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/phaser-split.js'),
      'pixi': path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/pixi.js'),
      'p2': path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/p2.js'),
    }
  },
  /**
  postcss: function () {
    return [precss, autoprefixer(AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS)];
  },
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
  },
   **/
}
```

And here is how I am importing Phaser into my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import cookie from "react-cookie";
import pixi from 'phaser';
import p2 from 'phaser';
import Phaser from 'phaser';
```

I'm using this NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/phaser

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your expose loader config looks different than the docs @ https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader

Are you sure you want to use Phaser within a React component? It seems like unnecessary complexity, seeing as how both Pixi and React want complete ownership over rendering..